# SQL Server, VIEWS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay guys, I'm trying to create a VIEW in SQL SERVER for the most popular payment method

```
CREATE VIEW payType

AS

SELECT SaleID, PayID
FROM tblSales
GROUP BY
tblSales.SaleID, tblSales.PayID
```

Comment: How do you calculate the % of each `PayID`?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Any other tables of interest?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your looking for the number of SaleID's that have used each payment method, your select statement will want to be something like this;

```
SELECT a.PayID
    ,COUNT(a.SaleID) Sales
    ,(COUNT(a.SaleID) / b.Tot)*100 = PercentOfTotal
FROM tblSales a
JOIN (
    SELECT SaleID
        ,COUNT(PayID) Tot
    FROM tbl.Sales
    GROUP BY SaleID
    ) b ON a.SaleID = b.SaleID
GROUP BY a.PayID
ORDER BY COUNT(a.SaleID) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, Could you explain what the 'a' and 'b' are used for?

Comment: They're aliases on the tables, it makes it easier to see which data is used where. you can also show it like this; FROM tblSales AS a

Comment: Great explanation, I'm also going to ask. The 'b.Tot'  would that be a new entity I would have to create or can that be just within the view? What's its purpose?

Comment: the b.Tot refers to the field called Tot ('COUNT(PayID) Tot') from the sub query called 'b'